# Two infinite radicals question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Hello I have stucked with theese two questions:

$\sqrt{a:\sqrt{a:\sqrt{a: \cdots}}} + \sqrt[3]{a\cdot\sqrt[3]{a\cdot\sqrt[3]{a\cdots}}} = 12$

$a=\text{ ?}$

---

$\sqrt{6+\sqrt{7+\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6- \cdots}}}}}=?$

Comment: What does the $:$ operator do in the first one?

Comment: : is the division operator

Comment: Assuming the $.$ operator is multiplication, $$\sqrt[3]{a.\sqrt[3]{a.\sqrt[3]{\dots}}}=\sqrt a$$

Comment: For second question, Let $x=\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6-...}}}$, we have $6-x=x^2$. Can you find $x$?

Comment: What is the full  sequence of constants in the second question? If it is all  "6-"  after the part shown, it is easy .

Comment: Still confused with that, couldn't solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sqrt{a/\sqrt{a/\sqrt{a/ ...}}}=a^\frac{1}{2}/(a^{\frac{1}{4}}/(a^{\frac{1}{8}}...))=a^{\sum_{i=1}^{\inf}\frac{1}{2*(-2)^{i-1}}}=a^{\frac{1}{3}} $

$\sqrt[3]{a\sqrt[3]{a\sqrt[3]{a ...}}}=a^{\sum_{i=1}^{inf}\frac{1}{3i}}=a^{\frac{1}{2}}
$

Then we have $a^{\frac{1}{3}}+a^{\frac{1}{2}}=12$
Function $f(a)=a^{\frac{1}{3}}+a^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is strictly increasing so equation can't have more than 1 solution. It's easy to see that solution is 64.

For second part let $t=\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6-..}}$
But then $ t^2=6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6-..}}=6-t  $

$t^2+t-6=0$
Using t>0 we have t=2

then we get $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{7+t}}=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{9}}=\sqrt{6+3}=3 $

Comment: I have a question: how can we calculate the infinite ∑

Comment: In this task we have  geometric procresions with denominators which absolute values are less then 1 . For such progrseions exist formula $\sum_{i=1}^{inf}b_i=\frac{b_1}{1-q}$ where $b_1$-first element of progresion and $q$- denominaor .

Comment: In first progresion $b_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $q=-\frac{1}{2}$ so $S=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{3}$